# Confusion over predict() command in R

Tags: r, logistic, linear-model

I'm trying to use the command predict() to be able to obtain my $x_i\hat{\beta}$ in R

```
predict(logitmodel,type='response')
```

As long as I'm not specifying any coefficients for the function to predict, does it simply just give me $x_i\hat{\beta}$ or does it return $y_i$?

What if I have specified a logit distribution, say

```
logitmodel=glm(y,binomial(),data)
```

Does it then return the transformed $x_i\hat{\beta}$, i.e. $F(x_i\hat{\beta})$? Which for a logistitic distribution is, $\frac{exp(\hat{\beta}'x_i)}{1+exp\hat{(\beta}'x_i)}$.

Comment: See the `type` argument at `?predict.glm`. `type = "response"` gives the predicted probabilities, and `type = "link"` gives the linear predictor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the Logistic Distribution for a Logit Regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495735/how-do-i-find-the-logistic-distribution-for-a-logit-regression-in-r)